# The text on a TextButtonCell disappears when its row is selected

Tags: gwt

I have a `DataGrid`, and I set a column with `TextButtonCell`.

**If nothing is selected, everything is fine.**

[image]

**But once I select a row, the text on the button disappears.**

[image]

**How can I stop the text on the button disappearing?**

**Edit**

Below is the code I created this button column:

```
    Column<Publication, String> buttonColumn =
                    new Column<Publication, String>(new TextButtonCell()) {
                      @Override
                      public String getValue(Publication pub) {
                        ((TextButtonCell)getCell()).setEnabled(pub.isPublishable());
                        return "Publish";
                      }
                    };
   buttonColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Publication, String>() {
                  @Override
                  public void update(int index, Publication pub, String value) {
                      publish(pub);
                  }
                });
    pubDG.addColumn(buttonColumn);
```

Comment: Did you confirm in the browser that the text disappears instead of becoming invisible (eg has the same color as the button background)?

Comment: The problem may be in your getValue() method for this column. Can you post it?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Hi, I just return `"Publish"` in `getValue()`. Please have a look at my `Edit`.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I am not sure the text disappears or become invisible. I didn't do any anything special for the text color. All I can see are also on the pictures in this post.

Comment: This simply can be a css problem, e.g. style class 'selected-row' sets the 'text-color' for each cell, and for button it becomes the same as background. You definitely should check css properties for this button (when selected) with some tool (Firebug, Developer Tool for Chrome, etc.)

Comment: Looks alright in Chrome. I was able to reproduce it only in IE. Could it be a GWT bug?

Comment: I have the same problem. The test is white on a white background. I can't figure out what the CSS is because the text-edit-box disappears when I try to inspect the element! Please share if you fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use selection model if possible. May be it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If you wat to use selection model then override the css to change the color of text of selected row then you will be able to see the text of text button.